# MFC window maximized, but to wrong top coordinate

Tags: mfc, maximize-window

Sometimes, when I use ShowWindow(SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED), my MFC window is maximized, but it is not positioned at coordinates (0, 0), as it should, it is moved down, for around 30-40 pixels. Any tip on what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. In PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs), CREATESTRUCT was modified, like this

```
cs.style = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_MAXIMIZE;
```

Apparently, this was causing wrong WINDOWPLACEMENT coordinates. When changed to:

```
cs.style = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;
```

with call to

```
ShowWindows(SW_MAXIMIZE)
```

Everything worked fine.